# Why for nearest neighbour for point cloud data my code and standard code is not giving same result

Tags: matlab, nearest-neighbor, point-clouds

Hi I am new to Matlab and trying to work with Point Clouds. I picked a random point from the cloud and write a code to find out it's 10 Nearest neighbors. However, when i used the standard Matlab function, it is not giving the same result...can anyone explain why.. my code is:

```
ptCloud = pcread('Point Cloud\bunny\reconstruction\bun_zipper.ply');
xyz = ptCloud.Location;
N=size(xyz,1);
r=ceil((N/(100*rand))+10*rand);
point=x(r,:,:);

dist=sqrt(sum((xyz-repmat(point,N,1)).^2,2));

[d,ind]=sort(dist,'descend');

ind_closest = ind(1:10);

pt_closest = xyz(ind_closest,:,:);
```

**Output:**

```
[27955;14360;24204;13755;25659;14345;28071;24801;30746;25946]
```

while using standard function:

```
[ind1,d1]=**knnsearch**(xyz,point,'k',10);
```

**Output:**

```
1073    18275   18274   19122   18276   21598   20725   20724   1074    18273
```

Please tell me where I am doing it wrong?

Comment: You are sorting your distance in descending order. This means that the greatest distances appear first in the sorted result. Try to change the order to `'ascend'`.

Comment: Thanks a ton...:) How stupid of me :)